# General definition of the discriminant

Tags: definition, discriminant

There is a notion of the discriminant of

1. polynomials
2. quadratic forms
3. finite separable extensions of Dedekind domains (e.g., algebraic number fields)

I don't know much about 2, but I think that 1 and 3 measure ramification.

Do these three types of discriminants have a common generalization? Is there some general notion of what a discriminant *is*?

Comment: I'm guessing you've already looked here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant  and https://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/dedekind-domains-in-finite-separable-extensions/ .  The meaning of the word is that it is a measure that can be used to distinguish between different varieties of object (I use "distinguish" rather than "discriminate" because the latter has gained negative connotations since its original use).

Comment: Yes, I've seen both of those pages. I'm asking because I didn't find the section of the Wikipedia page on generalizations of the discriminant to be very edifying.